# Find Server from where to download Cerificate for Wi-Fi authentication

Tags: windows, networking

I am connected to my office network. Would like my PDA to connect to office wi-fi too. However even with credentials it says I need a certificate to connect to network.
I have an option to download certificate in pda from a server, however it needs server name or location I guess. Is there a way I can figure that out from my windows account from my laptop, that which server would be dispensing cerificates for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best off asking your netadmin(s) for this information directly.